# How to execute function when element changes? (Without setInterval)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried configuring my script to automatically click certain buttons on a page depending on what type of report is being shown (which is the text of the span element `.reportReason`).

Here's an example of what the page typically looks like: http://www.blankmediagames.com/Trial/viewReport.php?id=1409368
(I can't link the page to vote on reports since there is an excessive requirement that must be met by playing a game.)

After voting on a report, the webpage will remove all of the current report content and load all of the data from another report via Jquery. While it's loading the report (or while a report has not loaded), it sets all of the child div values of `#reportInfo` to "--" and removes all of the inner span classes from `#reportContent`.

This is the code for my script:

```
    switch ($('.reportReason').text()) {
    case "Inappropriate Username":
        //This is an INAPPROPRIATE USERNAME report
        reportIU();
        break;
    case "Spamming":
        //This is a SPAMMING report
        reportSpamming();
        break;
    case "Leaving":
        //This is a LEAVING report
        reportLeaving();
        break;
    case "Multi-accounting":
        //This is a MULTI-ACCOUNTING report
        reportMulti();
        break;
    default:
        //Report hasn't loaded or report type is 'Other'
        break;
}
```

I want to make it so that the switch statement will execute every time the text of the span element `.reportReason` changes and not after a set interval. Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: `$('.reportReason').on('change', function(){console.log($(this).text()})`

Comment: of what type is `$('.reportReason')` is it an `input`, is it a `div`, `span` - use the `<>` button to build a small example

Comment: Have a look here for more details - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Pilan It's a div element.

Comment: @DanielKrom This only causes it to execute the function repeatedly and stall the webpage. I'm looking for something that only executes the switch function once after every time the text of `.reportReason` changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tadaa :)

```js
$( '#btn' ).click( function() {
  // simulate ajax change
  if( $( 'div#test' ).text() != "a" ) {
    $( 'div#test' ).text( "a" );
  }
} );

$('div#test').on('DOMNodeInserted',function() {
  console.log('div changed!');
  
  // do your switchy stuff
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Div:
<div id='test'>Some randome content.</div><br/>
<br/>
<input id='btn' type='button' value='Change div content'/>
<br/>
```

Comment: I'll be sure to test this out as soon as I get home.

Comment: go home - now! :D

Comment: @LordNazo sure, take have a look at [selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) - for example `span.bla` all `span`s with class `bla`

Comment: Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/teqc48nd/ @Pilan is right in my opinion

Comment: @Emeeus updated your fiddle (jQuery was missing) - [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teqc48nd/2/)

Comment: Hi @Pilan you should include in your answer that [MutationEvents are deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events)  so *caveat emptor*.

Answer (score 0):

## [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

If `.reportReason` was a form control such as an input, textarea, checkbox, etc, it'd be far easier to access its data upon an event than it would with a span. Form controls have specialized events such as `change`, and `input` which deal with text, but then again that would depend upon user interaction which probably doesn't apply to your situation (in a direct manner at least).

Assuming that the text itself was from a source you have little or no control over, we will start at `span.reportReason` and determine when text has been inserted within. I suggest in the future that you trace the steps necessary to find the origin of the text itself. I'm sure this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

In order to monitor changes that occur upon `span.reportReason` we can use the **[MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)**. In the following Demo an observer is created to detect any changes of `span.reportReason` content. It will log changes as text is added or removed.
**Note:**  all lines that have a `console.log(...)` statement are the places you should place any calls to your functions. I wasn't about try to find those functions in the `switch()` so they were replaced by `console.log` which is sufficient proof that the code functions properly.

### Demo

**There are portions of the code marked: *"TEST NOT REQUIRED"* which means it's just included for demo purposes and it's not required for the solution itself.**

```js
var tgt = document.querySelector('.reportReason');
var cfg = {
  attributes: false,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true
};

var monitor = new MutationObserver(function(changes) {
  changes.forEach(function(change) {
    console.log();
    for (let i = 0; i < change.addedNodes.length; i++) {
      console.log(`MUTATION TYPE: ${change.type} | "${change.addedNodes[i].textContent}" added`);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < change.removedNodes.length; i++) {
      console.log(`MUTATION TYPE: ${change.type} | "${change.removedNodes[i].textContent}" removed`);
    }
  });
});


monitor.observe(tgt, cfg);

function reportReason(e) {

  const flag = $('.reportReason').text();

  switch (flag) {
    case "Inappropriate Username":
      console.log(`‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
REASON: Username sux.`);
      break;
    case "Spamming":
      console.log(`‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
REASON: User is spamming scum.`);
      break;
    case "Account not validated":
      console.log(`‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
REASON: User has not validated account yet.`);
      break;
    case "Multiple accounts":
      console.log(`‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
REASON: User has multiple accounts, delete all but the newest account.`);
      break;
    default:
      console.log(`‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
REASON: Specific Flag: ${flag}`);
      break;
  }
}



// TEST NOT REQUIRED

$('button').on('click', function() {
  let flag = $('#test').val();
  $('.reportReason').text(flag);
  reportReason();
});

// TEST NOT REQUIRED
```

```css
.as-console-row:after {
  display: none !important
}

select,
button {
  font: inherit
}
```

```html
<!--TEST NOT REQUIRED-->
<fieldset class='set'>
  <legend>Test</legend>
  <select id='test'>
    <option></option>
    <option>Inappropriate Username</option>
    <option>Spamming</option>
    <option>Account not validated</option>
    <option>Multiple accounts</option>
    <option>Other Reason...</option>
  </select>
  <button type='button'>TEST</button>
</fieldset>
<!--TEST NOT REQUIRED-->

<div>
  <span class="rititle">Reported Reason:</span>
  <span class="rivalue">
    <span class="reportReason"></span>
  </span>
</div>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```